# How to relative import a module from another directory in the top directory (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a project structured the following way:

```
project/ 
    main.py
    package1/
        module1.py
        module2.py
        subpackage1/
            module4.py
    package2/
        module3.py
```

```
# main.py
from package1 import module1
```

```
# module1.py
from . import module2
from .subpackage1 import module4
```

```
# module4.py
from .. import module2
```

If I run `python main.py` from the top directory, it is all fine so far. However, if I add the following line to `module1.py`

```
# module1.py
from . import module2
from .subpackage1 import module4
from ..package2 import module3     # add this line
```

I get the error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. How should one **relative import** the module in another directory of the top directory? Or is that not possible?

Another curious finding is that the following works

````
from . import module2
from .subpackage1 import module4   # this line does NOT work without the '.' relative import
from package2 import module3       # removing relative import works ```
````

Comment: Just use    'from package2 import module3
'

Comment: I realized `from package2 import module3` worked, but I'm still curious why `from ..package2` does not. I understand you can jump beyond the top level, but even towards top level is not allowed?

Comment: I meant to say "I understand you CANNOT jump beyond the top level". Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't allow you to jump up to a different top-level package which is why you are getting the error. You should consider using an absolute import.

```
from . import module2
from .subpackage1 import module4
from package import module3
```

This should work if the project file is in your python path.
hope this helps

Comment: I realized `from package2 import module3` worked, but I'm still curious why `from ..package2` does not. I understand you cannot jump beyond the top level, but even towards top level is not allowed?

Comment: In Python, relative imports (from .. syntax) are used to import modules or subpackages within the same package. They are not designed to jump beyond the top-level package. To import modules from a different top-level package, you should use an absolute import, like from package2 import module3. Relative imports are limited to referencing elements within the current package.